# External CSS Height not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style my page with an external style page. Some of my div's pick up all the styling and some don't. In particular, all of the ones with an image file in them take all the styling except the height and/or width. The z-position, left, top etc. all work fine. I check the DOM explorer and it doesn't show that it's inheriting it's size from the body tag but I cannot figure out why it wont size them properly.

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="race_inprogress.css">
        <script type='text/JavaScript' src="race.js" language=javascript></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1 class = "amazing"> The Amazing Race For an A! </h1>

        <h1 class = "fordmeis"> Professor Ford Vs Michael Meis </h1>

        <div id="traffic-light">
        <div id="stopLight" class="bulb"></div>
        <div id="slowLight" class="bulb"></div>
        <div id="goLight" class="bulb"></div>
        </div>

        <input type=button onClick="illuminateGreen();timer();" value='Go!' style="position: absolute; left: 545px; top:265px;"> 

        <div class = "racer1">
            <img src=images/teacher.jpg id='i1'>
        </div>
            <br><br><br><br>
        <div class = "racer2">
            <img src=images/meis.png id='i2'>
        </div>

        <div class = "road1">
            <img src=images/road.jpg>
        </div>

        <div class = "road2">
            <img src=images/road.jpg>
        </div>

        <div class = "winners">
            <img src=images/winner_ford.png id='image1' onclick="reset()">
            <br><br><br><br>
            <img src=images/winner_meis.png id='image2' onclick="reset()">
        </div>

        <script>
            illuminateRed()
            hideImage()
        </script>

    <div class="vertical-line">
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    html
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body 
{
font-family: sans-serif;
background: url("images/checkback.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
overflow-x: hidden; 
}

div.racer1
{
    width: 10px;
    position:absolute;
    left: 25px;
    top: 325px;
    z-index: 2; 
}

div.racer2
{
    width: 10px;
    position:absolute;
    left: 25px;
    top: 500px;
    z-index:2;
}

div.road1
{
    position:absolute;
    left: 30px;
    top: 325px;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 133px;
    width: 1180px:
}

div.road2
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    top: 500px;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 133px;
    width: 1180px;
}

div.winners
{
    position:absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

h1.amazing
{
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
    left: 20px;
    color: gold;
}

h1.fordmeis
{
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
    top: 90px;
    left: 700px;
    color: gold;
}

#traffic-light 
{
height: 200px;
width: 100px;
left: 500px;
position: absolute;
background-color: #333;
border-radius: 40px;
margin: -100px 0;
padding: 20px;
}

.bulb 
{
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
background-color: #111;
border-radius: 50%;
margin: 15px auto;
transition: background 500ms;
}

div.vertical-line
{
width: 0px;
height: 315px;
top: 55px;
position:relative;
left: 1200px;
color: gold;
border: 10px inset;
z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define images' height and width inline in img tags. `<img src="path/to/image" height="42" width="42">`

Comment: It works just fine with inline tags, but this is for a school project and the instructor specified at the beginning of the course to use external style sheets

Comment: Try this one 
.racer1 img {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}

Comment: Ah, width="" on a tag is not CSS but rather an actual HTML tag attribute. If you get into page rendering and painting technically it is recommended for images to at least have a width set so there aren't multiple calculations. Adding an attribute like style="width:100px" would be considered inline styles.

Comment: thank you Anuj and Nick, I had to set the initial size in the HTML and then style it with the CSS from there.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say exactly without the images for reference. A working example would be helpful to confirm (there looks to be external JS as well). One of the main culprit questions though: are the images larger than the containers inside of them? If so and you don't set the images to have a max-width of a 100% then they will break outside of set layout widths/heights. If you want the images to be cropped instead, adding in overflow: hidden would maintain those exact widths and not show all of the image.

Comment: i'm not sure I totally follow what you are saying. There is js as well, I didn't think it was relevant so I didn't include it. The exact same styles worked fine as long as I was using inline tags, it only stops working when I move it to an external style sheet. The images are both larger than what I am displaying them as, but I thought the width and height tags would size them down, is that not accurate?

Comment: if you want to see the full code working I can share it with you on google drive, I tried to get a fiddle working but couldn't figure it out. I'm not very good at this stuff.

Comment: The example you posted didn't have images with set inline heights or widths. If you don't have inline widths set (e.g <img src="" width="100">) that is likely to be the culprit since you mention that the images are indeed bigger. Does adding img { max-width:100% } to your styles resolve the problem? If you are sure JS has no influence then probably no worries there.

Comment: Since it looks like this is for a project to use external CSS Anuj or my answer will resolve your issue. His would be HTML based and mine would be CSS based. Down the road, you might consider the CSS as an extra safe measure when HTML widths for images are set wider than their parent containers. It is also good practices to use images similar in size to what they will be viewed at or possibly double size if retina/HD screens are a consideration.

Comment: I am feeling really dumb now that I am thinking about this. I am not setting the initial size of the image in the HTML when I input the image. Thank you guys for your help.